# How can we create primary key as a decimal data type, and can it be auto increment

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key

in my database we have a field which is going beyond int max value,
i can choose bigint for primary key but i am wondering can we use decimal(2,18) for primary key and if we can than how we auto increment this field ?

Comment: In SQL Server, `DECIMAL` is always specified with `(precision, scale)` where `precision` is the **total** number of digits, and `scale` is the number of digits after the decimal point. So your `decimal(2,18)` makes no sense at all - 2 digits overall, and 18 of those after the decimal point?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a decimal as a primary key, but it must have a scale of 0.
SQL Server will handle the auto-incrementing.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
     id decimal(18,0) identity primary key, 
     some_column varchar(200)
);
```

Reference:  http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10331/sql-server-what-are-the-data-types-supported-in-identity-columns.aspx

See your master plan in action here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e491d/1/0